# Isolated mitochondria in glucose rich solution, what happens to ATP generation?

Tags: cell-biology, metabolism, mitochondria, glucose

I'm taking intro to biology course this year, and I was thinking about this question.

> Isolated mitochondria were placed in a glucose rich solution. (With ADP and Pi). How would this affect the ATP creation in the solution ?

My very simplified understanding of the process is as follows:

1. Glycolysis takes place in the cytosol, and converts glucose into pyruvate.
2. Pyruvate enters the mitochondrion and is oxidized to acetyl CoA
3. Acetyl CoA enters the citric acid cycle which creates NADH and FADH2
4. In the electron transport chain, NADH and FADH2 electrons pass through the mitochondria membrane, this flow results in active proton transport out of the matrix, creating a gradient. And the result is diffusion of protons which is coupled with synthesis of ATP.

I was unsure what would happen when isolated mitochondria and placed in a glucose rich solution.

Reasonable options are:

1. My book states that ATP synthesis is reversible and ATP synthase can also act as an ATPase, hydrolyzing ATP to ADP and Pi if there is too much ATP.
2. There is no cytosol (due to the mitochondria being isolated), There is actually no glycolysis happening, meaning no citric acid cycle, and no electron transport chain, meaning no ATP.
3. There is not enough ATP to start the process: break glucose into fructose and pyruvates?
4. Or just nothing happens and ATP is generated regularly ?

Comment: As is usual with this kind of posting, we are being asked not about a problem or principal of biology but about a contrived examination question with ambiguous wording, the expected answer to which depends on the specific level of teaching in a given syllabus. While sympathizing with the poor student, I regard this as akin to mind reading. “How would this affect ATP creation?” Creation?  Phosphorylation of ADP? biosynthesis? Abiogenesis? “Affect” it? Was it happening already? Really, if the educator wants to test whether a student knows where glycolysis occurs he should ask it straight.

Comment: While I do agree that the wording is ambiguous, I did state that my teaching level was intro to biology course. I appreciate the sympathy, and would be happy with any biological explanation that is related to my question (simplified as it might be). I think the the question indeed meant Phosphorylation of ADP.

Comment: Well for an introductory biology course (unless it's at MIT) I would imagine the answer is what you have deduced yourself in 2. As glycolysis only occurs in the cytoplasm, adding glucose to isolated mitochondria is like spitting into the wind. Phosphorylation of ADP cannot occur because there is no enzyme system in the mitochondrion that can convert glucose into a substrate that can feed into the TCA cycle.